# ORIENTDB customize Order By in sql query

Tags: orientdb

Well, I got these indexes in this format like this 10.9.8.1 in a string.

I want to order records with SQL query in order by most significant int left.

like:

1

1.3

1.3.1

1.3.4

1.3.5

7.8

10.4.5

10.5

11.3

How this can be achieved?

Comment: Is the field on which you want to do the sort a string?

Comment: Hi @AlbertoAndeliero it could be useful a js function?

Comment: it works in this form? select from documents order by custom_js_fun(index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a javascrip function with the parameter "yourProperty" like this:

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var result=[];
var list=[];
var b=g.command("sql","select from v");
for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        var record=b[i];
        var index=record.getProperty(yourProperty);
        index+="."+record.getId().toString();
        var vector=index.split('.');
        list.push(vector);
}

list.sort(function (a, b) {
    var dim1=a.length-1;
    var dim2=b.length-1;
    for(j=0;j<dim1;j++){  
        var value1=parseInt(a[j]);
        if(j<dim2){   
            var value2=parseInt(b[j]);
            if(value1>value2)
                return 1;
            else if (value1<value2)
                return -1;
        }
    }
    if(dim1>dim2)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
});

for(m=0;m<list.length;m++){ 
  var element=list[m];
  var id=element[element.length-1];
  for(h=0;h<b.length;h++){
    var id2=b[h].getId().toString();
        if(id==id2){
            result.push(b[h]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

return result;
```

[image]

Hope it helps.